# How to make HIbernate fetch all properties of root entity and only specific properties of associated entity?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have root entity `Hostel` and its single association `User owner`.

When I fetch `Hostel` entity I need to eagerly fetch `User owner`, but only `owner`'s 3 properties : userId,firstName,lastName.

For now my criteria query is :

```
Criteria criteria = currenSession().createCriteria(Hostel.class);

criteria.add(Restrictions.ge("endDate", Calendar.getInstance()));
if (StringUtils.notNullAndEmpty(country)) {
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("country", country));
}

Long count = (Long) criteria
            .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
            .setProjection(Projections.rowCount()).uniqueResult();

criteria.setFetchMode("owner", FetchMode.SELECT);
criteria.addOrder(Order.desc("rating"));

// needed to reset previous rowCount projection
criteria.setProjection(null);

// retrieve owner association
criteria.createAlias("owner", "owner", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN)
        .setProjection(
                Projections.projectionList()
                        .add(Projections.property("owner.userId"))
                        .add(Projections.property("owner.firstName"))
                        .add(Projections.property("owner.lastName")));

criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);
```

Next, I do `criteria.list()` and I get sql statement which selects only `owner`'s 3 properties as specified in projection list. But it doesn't select any property of root `Hostel` entity.
Generated query is:

```
select
    owner1_.user_id as y0_,
    owner1_.firstName as y1_,
    owner1_.lastName as y2_ 
from
    HOSTEL this_ 
left outer join
    USER owner1_ 
        on this_.owner_fk=owner1_.user_id 
where
    this_.end_date>=? 
    and this_.country=?        
order by
    this_.rating desc limit ?
```

This query doesn't work because it returns five `Map`s which are empty. FIve maps are because there are five `Hostel` rows that match where condition. I created simple sql query and it works fine so the problem is only here.

How to force hibernate to fetch all properties of root `Hostel` entity and only 3 properties of asociated `User owner` entity?

**EDIT**
I tried to use `getSessionFactory().getClassMetadata(Hostel.class)` but it gave error about mapping enum in `Hostel`. So I fallback to list `Hostel` properties manually. For now my criteria query is:

```
// retrieve owner association
        criteria.createAlias("owner", "owner", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);
        criteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                .add(Projections.property("hostelId"))
                .add(Projections.property("address"))
                .add(Projections.property("country"))
                .add(Projections.property("region"))
                .add(Projections.property("gender"))
                .add(Projections.property("owner.userId"))
                .add(Projections.property("owner.firstName"))
                .add(Projections.property("owner.lastName")));

List<Hostel> hostels = criteria.list();

for (Hostel hostel : hostels) { // at this line I get error java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.home.hostme.entity.Hostel
            User owner = hostel.getOwner();
            System.out.println("owner=" + owner);
        }
```

Note that I removed `ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP` result transformer. This generated such mysql query :

```
select
    this_.hostel_id as y0_,
    this_.address as y1_,
    this_.country as y2_,
    this_.region as y3_,
    this_.gender as y4_,
    owner1_.user_id as y5_,
    owner1_.firstName as y6_,
    owner1_.lastName as y7_ 
from
    HOSTEL this_ 
left outer join
    USER owner1_ 
        on this_.owner_fk=owner1_.user_id 
where
    this_.end_date>=? 
    and this_.country=? 
order by
    this_.rating desc limit ?
```

At for-each loop  get such an error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.home.hostme.entity.Hostel
    at com.home.hostme.dao.impl.HostelDaoImpl.findHostelBy(HostelDaoImpl.java:168)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy64.findHostelBy(Unknown Source)
    at com.home.hostme.service.HostelService.findHostelBy(HostelService.java:27)
    at com.home.hostme.service.HostelService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$74db5b21.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:698)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631)
    at com.home.hostme.service.HostelService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$7af3bc10.findHostelBy(<generated>)
    at com.home.hostme.web.hostel.HostelController.doSearch(HostelController.java:94)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This error means that I don't have type `Hostel` in resulting list `hostels`.
I even tried to find out class of elements in resulting list 'hostels' with this:

```
List hostels = criteria.list();
        System.out.println("firstRow.class=" + hostels.get(0).getClass());
```

It printed:

```
firstRow.class=class [Ljava.lang.Object;
```

Then I tried to set `ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP` for new ProjectionList, but resulting list 'hostels' was:

```
[{}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
```

Five empty maps. Five because there are 5 rows in db(table hostel) matching where clause.

Then I deleted projection list completely and hibernate retrieved 5 hostels and 5 associated `User owner`s and `owner`'s images as expected.

THE PROBLEM is how to stop hibernate retrieve associated `Image` entity of associated `User owner`. The best would be to fetch only 3 specific props of associated `User owner`.

Thank you!

Comment: If u always required these 3 columns from User, then you mention lazy is false to other properties and try to load Hostel instance.

Comment: I cannot change entities . I need to do it in criteria api. I tried to call setFetchMode(LAZY) on `owner` association but it fetches all props of `User owner` eagerly anyway

Comment: Please can you clarify a few things: 1. Please could you update your question to include the code for the Hostel and User class? 2. Why do you have to use criteria? As Serge has given a good answer for HQL below? 3. Why do you only want those fields from the user? Are there other fields in the user that you think will cause a performance problem? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, `User` entity has `Image` association with FetchMode.EAGER and I don't need to fetch `Image` eagerly only in my case. HQL is possible but I thought that criteria is the right way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Can you also clarify - what are you doing with the data once you have retrieved it? Do you want Hostel objects linked to User objects, or do you just need specific property values from each Hostel and associated User?

Comment: I need specific properties values of `Hostel` and associated `User owner` to create row in html table

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it with a direct query :

```
Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT hostel, owner.id, owner.firstname, "
        +"owner.lastname FROM Hostel hostel LEFT OUTER JOIN hostel.ower AS owner");
List list = query.list();
```

generates a SQL like :

> select hostel0_.id as col_0_0_, user1_.id as col_1_0_, user1_.firstname as col_2_0_, user1_.lastname as col_3_0_, hostel0_.id as id1_0_, hostel0_.name as name2_0_, ..., hostel0_.owner_id as user_id4_0_ from Hostel hostel0_ left outer join User user1_ on user1_.id=hostel0_.owner_id

with all the fields from Hostel and only required fields from User.

The list obtained with `criteria.list()` is a `List<Object[]>` whose rows are 
`[ Hostel, Integer, String, String]`

You can obtain something using `Criteria`, but `Criteria` are more strict than queries. I could not find any API that allows to mix entities and fields. So as far as I know, it is not possible to get rows containing an entity (Hostels) and separate fields from an association (owner.userId, owner.firstName, owner.lastName).

The only way I can imagine would be to explicitely list all fields from Hostels :

```
criteria.createAlias("owner", "owner", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN)
    .setProjection(
            Projections.projectionList()
                    .add(Projections.property("hostelId"))
                    .add(Projections.property("country"))
                    .add(Projections.property("endDate"))
                    ...
                    ... all other properties from Hostel
                    ...
                    .add(Projections.property("owner.userId"))
                    .add(Projections.property("owner.firstName"))
                    .add(Projections.property("owner.lastName")));
```

You can automate it a little by using Metadata (don't forget the id ...) - note : I use aliased projection only to be able later to use a wrapper class, if you directly use the scalar values, you can safely omit the `Projection.alias` :

```
    ProjectionList hostelProj = Projections.projectionList();
    String id = sessionFactory.getClassMetadata(Hostel.class)
            .getIdentifierPropertyName();
    hostelProperties.add(Projections.alias(Projections.property(id),id));
    for (String prop: sessionFactory.getClassMetadata(Hostel.class).getPropertyNames()) {
        hostelProperties.add(Projections.alias(Projections.property(prop), prop));
    }
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Hostel.class);
    criteria.createAlias("owner", "owner", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);
    criteria.setProjection(
            Projections.projectionList()
                    .add(hostelProj)
                    .add(Projections.property("owner.id"))
                    .add(Projections.property("owner.firstName"))
                    .add(Projections.property("owner.lastName")));
    List list = criteria.list();
```

That way correctly generates

> select this_.id as y0_, this_.name as y1_, ..., this_.user_id as y3_, owner1_.id as y4_, owner1_.firstname as y5_, owner1_.lastname as y6_ from hotels this_ left outer join users owner1_ on this_.user_id=owner1_.id

But you will not be able to use `criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP)` because the resultset is not exactly the image of the fields from `Hostel` (even without the aliases).
In fact the list is a `List<Object[]>` with rows containing all individual fields from `Hostel` followed by the 3 required fields from `owner`.

You will have to add a wrapper class containing a `Hostel` and the 3 other fields to make use of an `AliasToBeanResultTransformer` and get true `Hostel` objects :

```
public class HostelWrapper {
    private Hostel hostel;
    private int owner_id;
    private String owner_firstName;
    private String owner_lastName;

    public HostelWrapper() {
        hostel = new Hostel();
    }

    public Hostel getHostel() {
        return hostel;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        hostel.setId(id);
    }
    public void setOwner(User owner) {
        hostel.setOwner(owner);
    }
    // other setters for Hostel fields ...

    public int getOwner_id() {
        return owner_id;
    }
    public void setOwner_id(Integer owner_id) {
    // beware : may be null because of outer join
        this.owner_id = (owner_id == null) ? 0 : owner_id;
    }
    //getters and setters for firstName and lastName ...
}
```

And then you can successfully write :

```
criteria.setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(HostelWrapper.class));
List<HostelWrapper> hostels = criteria.list();

Hostel hostel = hostels.get(0).getHostel();
String firstName = hostels.get(0).getFirstName();
```

I could verify that when there is no owner `hostel.getOwner()` is null, and when there is one, `hostel.getOwner().getId()` is equal to `getOwner_id()` and that this access does not generate any extra query. But any access to an other field of `hostel.getOwner()`, even `firstName` or `lastName` generates one because the `User` entity was not loaded in session.

The most common usage should be :

```
for (HostelWrapper hostelw: criteria.list()) {
    Hostel hostel = hostelw.getHostel();
    // use hostel, hostelw.getOwner_firstName and hostelw.getOwner_lastName
}
```

Comment: @VolodymyrLevytskyi : it works now (in my tests ...) but I had to use a wrapper class around Hostel and the 3 fields from owner. Post edited.

Comment: How to map `Hostel hostel` of `HostelWrapper` to projection list in criteria?

Comment: @VolodymyrLevytskyi I'm not sure to understand your last question. I put in the projection list all fields from `Hostel` aliased with their name, and the 3 fields from `User`, then the `AliasToBeanResultTransformer` transforms each row in a `HostelWrapper` containing a `Hostel` and the 3 other fields. I edited my post for a more *normal* usage.

Comment: @VolodymyrLevytskyi Can I somehow retrieve the parent entity and a particular property of a all child entities as list ?

Comment: @SergeBallesta I think I have same issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45234946/3425489, Can you please, help me to form HQL query or by using projections.

Answer (score 3):

@Serge Ballesta solved my issue but here is my final working code:

```
Criteria criteria = currenSession().createCriteria(Hostel.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.ge("endDate", Calendar.getInstance()));
        if (StringUtils.notNullAndEmpty(country)) {
            criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("country", country));
        }
Long count = (Long) criteria
                .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
                .setProjection(Projections.rowCount()).uniqueResult();

// mark query as readonly
        criteria.setReadOnly(true);
        // descendingly sort result by rating property of Hostel entity
        criteria.addOrder(Order.desc("rating"));
        // reset rowCount() projection
        criteria.setProjection(null);

ProjectionList hostelProjList = Projections.projectionList();
        ClassMetadata hostelMetadata = getSessionFactory().getClassMetadata(
                Hostel.class);
        // add primary key property - hostelId
        hostelProjList.add(Projections.property(hostelMetadata
                .getIdentifierPropertyName()), "hostelId");
        // add all normal properties of Hostel entity to retrieve from db
        for (String prop : hostelMetadata.getPropertyNames()) {
            //skip associations
            if (!prop.equals("owner") && !prop.equals("images")
                    && !prop.equals("requests") && !prop.equals("feedbacks"))
                hostelProjList.add(Projections.property(prop), prop);
        }
        // add properties of User owner association to be retrieved
        hostelProjList
                .add(Projections.property("owner.userId"), "owner_id")
                .add(Projections.property("owner.firstName"), "owner_firstName")
                .add(Projections.property("owner.lastName"), "owner_lastName");

        // create alias to retrieve props of User owner association
        criteria.createAlias("owner", "owner", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);
        criteria.setProjection(hostelProjList);

        criteria.setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(
                HostelWrapper.class));

List<HostelWrapper> wrappers = criteria.list();
```

And my `HostelWrapper` is :

```
public class HostelWrapper {
    private Hostel hostel;
    private int owner_id;
    private String owner_firstName;
    private String owner_lastName;

    public HostelWrapper() {
        hostel = new Hostel();
    }

    public Hostel getHostel() {
        return hostel;
    }

    public void setHostelId(Integer hostelId) {
        this.hostel.setHostelId(hostelId);
    }

public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.hostel.setCountry(country);
    }
public int getOwner_id() {
        return owner_id;
    }

    public void setOwner_id(Integer owner_id) {
        this.owner_id = owner_id == null ? 0 : owner_id;
    }

    public String getOwner_firstName() {
        return owner_firstName;
    }

    public void setOwner_firstName(String owner_firstName) {
        this.owner_firstName = owner_firstName;
    }

    public String getOwner_lastName() {
        return owner_lastName;
    }

    public void setOwner_lastName(String owner_lastName) {
        this.owner_lastName = owner_lastName;
    }
```

This `HostelWrapper` is used by `AliasToBeanResultTransformer` to map hibernate resultset to entities.

My final conclusion is that HQL is right way to go when you want to set projection on association.
With `AliasToBeanResultTransformer` you are bound to properties names and with hql is the same. Benefit is that HQL is much easier to write.

Answer (score 1):

As per my observation you cant get result as per you require.

We can done using the following steps:

```
String[] propertyNames = sessionFactory.getClassMetadata(Hostel.class).getPropertyNames();

ProjectionList projectionList = Projections.projectionList();

for (String propString : propertyNames) {
                projectionList.add(Projections.property(propString));
}
```

Please change the code as per below

```
criteria.createAlias("owner", "owner", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN)
        .setProjection(
                projectionList
                        .add(Projections.property("owner.userId"))
                        .add(Projections.property("owner.firstName"))
                        .add(Projections.property("owner.lastName")));
```

Please try and lemme know.

Comment: Tried it before. It doesn't retrieve any row. But if I remove projectionList, it retrieves expected rows. I don't know why is that.

Comment: In that projectionList only I added the Hostel params. So we need to add owner reference on top of that.

Comment: I did as you told and received zero rows

Comment: Please paste the query which is generated

Comment: The same as provided except all hostels properties are listed. The query itsef is ok but the result is zero which is strange as data  is in database

Comment: @VolodymyrLevytskyi No . I have tested locally it was working fine. Just i wanna see query. Then , what is the use of criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);